# What's the syntax to write a function in .profile linux mint

Tags: bash, homestead, linux-mint

I'm trying to add a function  to my ~/.profile file. I'm copying it from the laravel homestead installation guide: [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead)
as the guide says:

```
function homestead() {
    ( cd ~/Homestead && vagrant $* )
}
```

if I do "source .profile" it works just fine but if i reboot i get:

> Syntax error "(" unexpected and the system don't let me log in anymore

I tried to remove the parenthesis like this:

```
function homestead{
        cd ~/Homestead && vagrant $*
}
```

but i get:

> syntax error near unexpected token `cd'

I have no shebang on the file, should i put it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You removed the wrong item. The POSIX-compliant definition of a function is

```
homestead() {
    ( cd ~/Homestead && vagrant $* )
}
```

`function` (with or without the `()`) is a `bash` extension borrowed from `ksh`. `source` implies you are running `bash`, but `.profile` is used by other POSIX-compliant shells that don't understand the `function` keyword.